# What does it mean by the extra pipeline in the type declaration in typescript

Tags: typescript

Recently I've declared a type like-

```
interface SomeType {
  property: {
    a: number;
    b: string;
  } | undefined;
}
```

But when I saved the type, the vscode (maybe prettier) converts it into-

```
interface SomeType {
  property:
    | {
        a: number;
        b: string;
      }
    | undefined;
}
```

So, you see there is an extra `|` symbol after the `property` key. So what exactly is it? Can anyone describe the behavior?

**Note: This only happens if I set `property: {a: number; b: string;} | undefined;`. If the `| undefined` is not set then everything is same as it is.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is exactly the same as if there was no leading `|`. It's simply a style choice. It allows, for example

```
let foo:
  | 'a'
  | 'b'
  | 'c';
```

whereas if the syntax did not permit the leading `|`, it'd have to look like

```
let foo:
    'a'
  | 'b'
  | 'c';
```

which might grind some people's gears.